# What is the serie convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(3n)!}{n^{3n}} $

Tags: limits, divergent-series

I am stucked with this example:

$$  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(3n)!}{n^{3n}} $$

Im proving this using d'alembert principle

So I have

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{(3(n+1))!}{(n+1)^{3(n+1)}}}{\frac{(3n)!}{n^{3n}}} $$

So after some calculations i get

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(3n)!(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)(n^{3n})}{(3n)!(n+1)^{3(n+1)}} $$

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)(n^{3n})}{(n+1)^{3n+3}} $$

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)(n^{3n})}{n^{3n+3}+1} $$

And I don't know how to cut the powers $n^{3n}$

$$ \frac {n^{3n}}{ n^{3n} * n^3 +1} $$

I will be very thankful for every help and explanation.
I hope I named this problem corectly in english cause it isnt my mother tongue.

Comment: You meant to use the limit as $n$ approaches infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ratio simplifies to 
$$
\frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}{(n+1)^3} \cdot \left(\frac{n}{n+1} \right)^{3n}
$$
Now the first factor goes to $3^3 = 27$. For the second factor use the well-known limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n+1}{n} \right)^n = e$. Therefore the entire limit is $\frac{27}{e^3} > 1$, and the series is therefore divergent.

Comment: Thank you so much, also wolframalpha says it is not converge. This is an example from my exam and my teacher in answer key said this is convergent so he made a mistake :)

Comment: How does $n^{3n+3} + 1$ simplify to $(n+1)^{3n+3}$?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing $3n=k$ and using the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) note that $$ \frac{k!}{(\frac {k}{3})^k} \sim_{+\infty} \frac {\sqrt{2\pi k} (\frac {k}{e})^k}{(\frac {k}{3})^k}= \sqrt{2\pi k}(\frac {3}{e})^k$$ but the series $$\sum_{k\ge 1} \sqrt{2\pi k}(\frac {3}{e})^k$$ diverges